# Is there a way to render grease pencil without the reference object

Tags: rendering

I made a cube and added a grease pencil stroke to create a line art of the cube. Now i turned the cube off in the renderd image to just render the grease pencil stroke lineart of the cube. No lineart is displayed at the rendered image. Can someone help me?[image]
[image]

Solved: I have to bake the lineart.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to bake the *Line Art* for various reasons, you could simply give the cube a *Transparent BSDF* set to full white as a material, this way it's invisible in the render but the lines still show. The other possibility would be to disable everything under *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* in the cube's *Object Properties*.

1. option: give the cube a material to make it invisible

[image: material]

2. option: disable all *Ray Visibility* settings

[image: ray visibility]

Answer (score 1):

Use a holdout shader:

[image]

> The *Holdout* shader node is used to create a “hole” in the image with zero alpha transparency, which is useful for compositing (see [Alpha Channel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/glossary/index.html#term-Alpha-Channel)).
>
> Source: [Holdout — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/holdout.html)

Comment: This will hide everything behind the object as well, which can be intended, or not, or irrelevant for OP.

Comment: Yes, in which case the other answer covers it all ;)